# How to handle a detail question if it has been answered in another more generalized question of the same author?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, old-questions

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434820/so-confused-with-property-descriptor-in-a-gridview) about some code, which in fact was referenced  to another more [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429933/what-is-this-code-for) about the same subject of the same author. The general question was answered and accepted. The accepted answer did also contain a note which gave in my eyes a correct answer to the detailed question.

The first question is now over a year old and was never responded to, so I decided to mark it as duplicate of the general question. The original author seemed to take this as an offense. Was I right to mark it as duplicate? Or what else should I have done to correctly deal with this?

Comment: It is a duplicate though. The **EDIT** in his first thread contains the same question and was adressed.

Comment: hhen closing a duplicate of a more general question, or a slightly different question, I usually add a comment, or edit the automatic comment, to explain a little bit about the connection.  (Beware though, these comments might get deleted automatically when the question is closed. :( (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3786/29288, and the questions it links to, especially http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414/225437).)

Comment: We have this issue all the time. Often, a single general problem (that fits well into a question and answer) is duplicated by 1000 slight variants that would all be answered by a single general question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I clarified the titles of both questions, and closed the dupe.  It seems like a clear duplicate to me.

It's hard to imagine how, after a year, the OP is *still* waiting for an answer.

Comment: *All good things come to him who waits... someday... maybe*